# QML: Unable to assign QQuickItem to QQuickAnchorLine

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to position item with id `containerItem` in main window with id `mainWindow` in the main.qml file. But I've got this message in output:

> Unable to assign QQuickWindowQmlImpl to QQuickItem

The message points on the string `anchors.fill: mainWindow`.
My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {

    visible: true
    color: "black"
    id : mainWindow

    width: 360
    height: 360

    Item {

        anchors.fill: mainWindow

        id: containerItem
    }
}
```

I'll be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Use `anchors.fill: mainWindow.contentItem` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Window` (`QQuickWindow`) is very specific. If you call that by child as parent (`anchors.fill:parent`), you receive `QQuickRootItem`, but if you use `id`, like in your example, you receive `QQuickWindowQmlImpl`.
If you want use `anchors.fill` by children, use `Window` as `parent`.
P.S. also `Window` hasn't anchors at all, and if you want stick to right in example, you must calculate width of window and object which you want stick, or you can wrap object to filled Item.

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id : mainWindow
    visible: true
    color: "black"
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Item {
        id: containerItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            anchors {
                right:parent.right
                bottom:parent.bottom
            }
            width: 80
            height: 80
            color: "pink"
        }
    }
}
```